# bug with ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a problem with the ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush resource. This brush doesn't work. At the begining the background is white and the application color theme is dark by default. And even if i change the color theme before starting the application it doesn 't do anything. I don't know why.

Event if i start a new universal project and then i run it on emulator or on my phone , the brush doesn't work.

m i doing something wrong ? For exemple :

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
```

Thanks in advance for your reply. I m running under windows 10 and the application is for windows 10 mobile.

Comment: "At the begining the background is white and the application color theme is dark by default." Are you developing an UWP app? And your "application color theme" means `RequestedTheme` of application? By default it should be light. How did you set this `RequestedTheme` ?

Comment: No no :) i want the theme color (dark or ligth) from the phone parameters.